# Unable to log in to my android app with the other facebook profiles

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk

I created an android application with facebook log in (using face book sdk 3.6.0), following the steps mentioned in developers site. After completion of my app I am able to log in with my facebook id but not with any other user id. It shows a dialog like logging in but wont let me log in and continue. I tried with both debug as well as the release Key hash, but still facing the log  in issue. What could be the reason and why am I not able to log in with other accounts. Please help.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: some one please help!. Got another crazy doubt. Is there any possibility that other users can log in to my application only if they downloaded it from play store( I mean to say only when it is released)?

Answer (score 0):

Goto https://developers.facebook.com/apps click on the app you have created. on the left side you can find Status and Review click on it. on the right pane you can see a toggle button with the question "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" make it on or yes. from now every can log in to your app using their profile credentials. Thank you.